# Axios Interceptor not intercepting error statuses when API called is made

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to intercept all the 401 responses and then redirecting them to another page.

This is what I have done for the instance

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.example.com/",
  withCredentials: true
});

// Add a response interceptor
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
        console.log('intercepted');
        window.location = "/login";
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);

export default instance;
```

And in my API services file, I am calling axios using the instance.

```
import axiosInstance from "../utils/axiosInstance";
const response = await axiosInstance.post("/player/new", bodyFormData);
```

This API will return 401 however the interceptor isn't catching it and I can see the failed request in the network dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the interceptor to your axios `instance` instead of `axios` itself, as pointed out in the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
        console.log('intercepted');
        window.location = "/login";
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Changed. However, this interceptor isn't called, are there more things to configure?

Comment: @Eneres I have tried to run your code and it works for me, probably the issue lies somewhere else

Comment: Yep tested again and the code works but for some reason error.response is null when intercepted instead of 401. Will check to investigate.